# Trying to make nested bookmarks whilst merging PDF file using PDF filename as bookmark python pypdf2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

Below is some code im working on which merges pdf files and creates a bookmark using the pdfs being merged filename. I know need to add nested bookmarks which has meant ive had to use the pdffilemerger.addbookmark instead of just putting bookmarks in merger.append. merger.addbookmark needs a page number as an argument whereas before they were automatically in the right place. as can be seen below i have tried to figure out a way to add the pagenum based on the previous pdfs page number but it needs to be a cumulative of all the previous PDFS. Can anyone help me with this?

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from glob import glob
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(r'filepath', f))]
os.chdir(r'filepath')

for file in onlyfiles:
    fileReader = PdfFileReader(open(file,'rb'))
    totalpages = fileReader.numPages
source_dir = os.getcwd()   
merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)  

oldextension = '.PDF'
newextension = '.pdf'

with os.scandir(source_dir) as files_and_folders:
    for element in files_and_folders:
        if element.is_file():
            root, ext = os.path.splitext(element.path)
            if ext == oldextension:
                new_path = root + newextension
                os.rename(element.path, new_path)
                file_counter += 1

def merge(path, output_filename):
    merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)
    content = merger.addBookmark("contents", 0, parent=None)
    parent = merger.addBookmark("moisture content", 0, parent=content)
    pdfpages = 0
    
    for pdffile in glob(path + os.sep + '*.pdf'):
        if pdffile[2:] == output_filename:
            continue
        
        fileReader = PdfFileReader(open(pdffile,'rb'))
        bookmark = os.path.basename(pdffile[:-4])
        merger.add_bookmark(bookmark, pdfpages, parent=parent)
        pdfpages = fileReader.numPages          
        print(f"Appending: '{pdffile}'")
    for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
        if item.endswith('pdf'):
            merger.append(item)
    merger.write(output_filename)
    merger.close()            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output",
                        dest="output_filename",
                        default="moisturecontent.pdf",
                        help="write merged PDF to FILE",
                        metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--path",
                        dest="path",
                        default=".",
                        help="path of source PDF files")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    merge(args.path, args.output_filename)

            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output",
                        dest="output_filename",
                        default="group1.pdf",
                        help="write merged PDF to FILE",
                        metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--path",
                        dest="path",
                        default=".",
                        help="path of source PDF files")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    merge(args.path, args.output_filename)
```

the above code creates a pdf file with the first bookmark on page 1 (or 0 in python terms) then the next bookmark at the end of the first but after that it doesnt work as indented as the pdfpage is not cumulative